# Picker View Functions Not Called

Tags: ios, swift, function, uipickerview

I am making an app with some text fields, and once pressed, the text field is supposed to have a picker view pop up from the bottom, and is supposed to show some of the arrays that I have added, but somehow, after putting print statements, I found out the most important two functions,

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String?
```

and

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int)
```

where I put the code where I put words on my picker view, doesn't run.
How do I fix this? thanks

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController{
    var blocking = [Automation.blockTime.quarterHour, .halfHour, .hour, .twoHour]
    var blockingString = ["Quarter Hour", "Half Hour", "Hour", "Two Hours"]
    var startTimeString = ["5:00AM","6:30AM","5:30AM","6:00AM","7:00AM","7:30AM","8:00AM","8:30AM","9:00AM","9:30AM","10:00AM"]
    var endTimeString = ["5:00PM","6:30PM","5:30PM","6:00PM","7:00PM","7:30PM","8:00PM","8:30PM","9:00PM","9:30PM","10:00PM"]
    var startTime = [300, 390, 330, 360, 420, 450, 480, 510, 540, 570, 600]
    var endTime = [Int]()

    @IBOutlet weak var block: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var endOfSchedule: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var StartOfSchedule: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var AppointmentTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var prorityTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var GoButton: UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        createPicker()
        createToolbar()
        for EachElemnt in startTime {
            endTime.append(EachElemnt + (12 * 60))
        }
    }

    func createPicker() {
        let dayPicker = UIPickerView()
        dayPicker.delegate = self

        endOfSchedule.inputView = dayPicker
        StartOfSchedule.inputView = dayPicker
        block.inputView = dayPicker

        //Customizations
        dayPicker.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray
    }

    func createToolbar() {
        let toolBar = UIToolbar()
        toolBar.sizeToFit()

        //Customizations
        toolBar.barTintColor = .black
        toolBar.tintColor = .white

        let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.dismissKeyboard))

        toolBar.setItems([doneButton], animated: false)
        toolBar.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

        prorityTextField.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
    }

    @objc func dismissKeyboard() {
        view.endEditing(true)
    }
}

extension ViewController: UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {
    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        var returnment = Int()
        if pickerView == endOfSchedule {
            returnment = endTimeString.count
            return endTimeString.count
        }else if pickerView == StartOfSchedule {
            returnment = startTimeString.count
            return startTimeString.count
        }else if pickerView == block {
            returnment = blocking.count
            return blocking.count
        }

        return returnment

        func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {

            var returnment = String()
            if pickerView == endOfSchedule {
                returnment = endTimeString[row]

            }else if pickerView == StartOfSchedule {
                returnment = startTimeString[row]

            }else if pickerView == block {
                returnment = blockingString[row]

            }
            print(returnment)
            return returnment
        }

        func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
            if pickerView == endOfSchedule {
                endOfSchedule.text = endTimeString[row]
            }else if pickerView == StartOfSchedule {
                StartOfSchedule.text = startTimeString[row]
            }else if pickerView == block {
                block.text = blockingString[row]
            }
        }

        func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusing view: UIView?) -> UIView {
            var label: UILabel

            if let view = view as? UILabel {
                label = view
            } else {
                label = UILabel()
            }

            label.textColor = .white
            label.textAlignment = .center
            label.font = UIFont(name: "Menlo-Regular", size: 17)
            if pickerView == endOfSchedule {
                label.text = endOfSchedule.text
            }else if pickerView == StartOfSchedule {
                label.text = StartOfSchedule.text
            }else if pickerView == block {
                label.text = block.text
            }

            return label
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you are missing with **dayPicker.dataSource = self**

Comment: Why are you implementing both `viewForRow` and `titleForRow`? Pick one.

Comment: I fixed the formatting of your code so you can the serious issue in your extension. You put most of the methods inside the first one as mentioned at the end of my answer.

Comment: Have you verified you actually see the correct values in the picker for each text field? The code you posted (and now deleted but based on the currently selected answer) will probably only show the data from the `blockingString` array and nothing else.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {

    if pickerView == endOfSchedule {

        return endTimeString.count
    }else if pickerView == StartOfSchedule {

        return startTimeString.count
    }else {

        return blocking.count
    }
}                                                                             

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    if pickerView == endOfSchedule {
        return endTimeString[row]

    }else if pickerView == StartOfSchedule {
        return startTimeString[row]

    }else  {
        return blockingString[row]
    }
}
```

Try to return with each condition and then try to debug it. Maybe it will work and it seems you missed dataSource.

Comment: The data source doesn't affect anything, but if I paste in your code, I get an error, Missing return in function expected return 'Int' or Missing return in function expected return 'String?'

Comment: @RyanDev put the last condition with only else instead of else if and it will work

Comment: I put all last else if to else, and it is still the same

Comment: @RyanDev i have updated the code in my post try again and now it should work :)

Comment: I just posted the code that actually works, It ACTUALLY WORKS!!

Comment: OK, that fixes the syntax error in the answer. But this still only covers a portion of the issues in the code posted in the question.

Comment: I just added another file that I forgot to post That should fix the code not compiling problem.

Comment: @RyanDev The compiling issue had nothing to do with the code in your question, it was a (now fixed) syntax error in this answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have several issues.

1. You never set the picker's `dataSource`. Add `dayPicker.dataSource = self`.
2. You have implemented both `titleForRow` and `viewForRow`. Only implement one of them.
3. None of your `if` statements will succeed because you are comparing a `UIPickerView` variable against a `UITextField` instance. I'm surprised your code even compiles.

To solve the last issue, you need to set the delegate of all of the text fields. Then implement the `textFieldDidBeginEditing` delegate method. In that, set a property to the text field. Then in all of your picker view methods, compare that text field property against your text field outlets so you know which text field is the current text field. Or check to see if each text field is the first responder.

Example:

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    if endOfSchedule.isFirstResponder {
        return endTimeString.count
    } else if StartOfSchedule.isFirstResponder {
        return startTimeString.count
    } else {
        return blocking.count
    }
}
```

Last thing, make sure you did not put some of these methods inside another method. The code you posted has some curly braces in the wrong place.

Answer (score 0):

`titleForRow:` is not getting called because you are also using `viewForRow:` method which is simply not possible to include in same delegate. You have to use only one of them.

**Solution**: In `viewForRow:` set label.text to the string you're returning in `titleForRow:` and remove `titleForRow:` method.